# Addition assignment won't assign inside conditional

Tags: php, operators, variable-assignment, addition

It is my (intuitive) understanding that using the addition assignment operator `+=` in PHP for variables of the integer type would yield the result of the addition, while incrementing the left-side operand by the value of the right-side operand at the same time.

This understanding appears to be wrong, hence my question. Considering the following snippet of code:

```
$itr = 10;
$incr = 10;

if ($itr += $incr > 10) { // evaluates as true...
    echo $itr; // but value of $itr remains unchanged
}
```

Why does it output 10 instead of 20?

The same happens using the ternary form:

```
echo ($itr += $incr > 10) ? $itr : 'neverhere'; // prints 10
// Note: I know that parentheses aren't really necessary here, it's just a personal practice.
```

What is going on?

---

**Edit:** Well, I found out that surrounding the expression `$itr += $incr` with parentheses fixes the apparent problem. Still, a proper explanation of why would be very cool. My appreciation in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php): The `>` is evaluated first and leads to `false`. When casted to an integer to add to your value, `false` is casted to `0`.

So:

```
$itr += $incr > 10
```

becomes:

```
$itr += ($incr > 10)
$itr += (false)
$itr += 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In if statement you are only evaluating the possibility of $itr being incremented by $incr, but you are not effectively INSTRUCTING the PHP to do that. So it never stores the new value.